# Is it possible to set a custom action for when a target value changes?

Tags: java, mapstruct

So we need to mark the object as changed when we detect that a value changes on the target object (this is the update scenario).
The setter methods can be invoked in many situations, but we only want to mark the object as changed if any target attribute value is changed during this mapping process.
Is it possible to do it? I didn't find anything about this on the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Check [`PropertyChangeSupport`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html) - this facilitates managing (adding, deleting, triggering, ...) listeners to be informed if some property of an object has changed - still some additional programming needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That would work but we need to control the situation in which the setter is invoked. The setter can be invoked in many situations, but we want to mark the object as changed only if some value changes during this mapping process.